# In a Pacemaker cluster, is there any way to set start-failure-is-fatal on a per resource basis?

Tags: redhat, cluster, pacemaker, corosync

I've got it set cluster-wide currently, but I'd really like it to be set to 'true' by default and false for only my Slave DRBD resource.

Using Pacemaker 1.1.12 and Corosync 1.4.8.

Answer (score 1):

`start-failure-is-fatal` is a cluster option, so unfortunately, you can only apply it cluster-wide.

Perhaps you could set `start-failure-is-fatal=false` cluster-wide, and then define `meta migration-threshold=n` for each primitive in cluster to achieve similar results.

*n*=1 for resources you want to move quickly and *n*=3 for resources you'd like to recover without moving.

Comment: I don't actually want the resource to move ; I just want Pacemaker to continue to try restarting until it works.

Comment: In that case, you'd set start-failure-is-fatal to false, and increase the migration threshold to some large number. It will then try  to start the resource that many times before giving up.